# Отслеживание процесса в Linux

Tags: linux, oracle

У меня работает приложение, которое запускает новые процессы, обращающиеся к БД (Oracle)
Но какие-то запросы отрабатывающие более 20-30 секунд сервер киляет

По логам приложения: он просто перестаёт писать лог, ошибок не выдаёт

Как мне понять/отследить что именно убивает на сервере мои процессы?

Comment: Ну там в настройках сервера посмотреть таймауты обработки запросов? Или я неправильно понял вопрос?

Comment: Тоже наткнулся на эту идею, но подобного ничего не нашёл

Comment: Ну а каким-нить `DataGrip для Oracle` посмотреть чё за фигня происходит?

Comment: Нашёл! Там была связка с другим приложением. Он не мог найти переменную окружения и потому килял процесс. Спасибо за помощь!